# Determine all positive integers $n$ such that: $n+d(n)+d(d(n))+\dotsb=2023$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, summation, divisor-sum

For a positive integer number $n>1$, we say that $d(n)$ is its *superdivisor* if $d(n)$ is the largest divisor of $n$ such that $d(n)<n$. Additionally, we define $d(0)=d(1)=0$. Determine all positive integers $n$ such that:
$$n+d(n)+d(d(n))+\dotsb=2023.$$

I didn't even understand this problem when I began solving it. I just now realized that if $d(n)<n$ it must mean that $d(d(n))<d(n)$, so the values of the sum must be decreasing, that means that after a finite number of steps we are going to have $d(d(\dotso d(n))\dotso)=d(1)=0$, so then I tried by saying that $n$ cannot be prime, because the smallest prime smaller than $2023$ is $2017$, so for $n=2017$ we have $$n+d(n)+d(d(n))+\dotsb=2017+1++0+0+0+0+\dotsb=2018,$$ so $n$ cannot be prime, but I am not sure what to do from there.

Comment: Where does this problem come from?  Are you expected to come up with an "analytic" argument, or is brute force good enough?

Comment: @Xander Henderson I have no idea where this problem comes from, my friend challenged me with it about a year ago, but I forgot to solve it, I think it is an excellent and fun problem, so I decided to share it with you. I believe it is supposed to be solved by analytic arguments, not brute force because it would be a computer science problem, not a math problem.

Comment: It may help to remark that,  for $n>1$, $d(n)$ is $\frac np$, where $p$ is the least prime dividing $n$.  Should add:  $d(n)$ is frequently used to denote $\sigma_0(n)$, the number of divisors of $n$.  As such, I suggest changing your notation to avoid confusion.

Comment: FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24n%2Bd(n)%2Bd(d(n))%2B%5Cldots%3D2023%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Asuperdivisor%2C%20OR%20content%3Apositive%20integers&p=1), there's the AoPS thread [n + d (n) + d (d (n)) +... = 2021 where d (k) is max divisor of k with d<k](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2582948p22237872), with it stating the source is "$2021$ Czech and Slovak Olympiad III A p$4$". Although that has a RHS value of $2021$ instead of $2023$, the techniques shown there should also be generally applicable to your problem as well.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Thanks, sorry I posted it as mine... Should I delete the question?

Comment: You're welcome, and there's no real need to apologize for posting it as "yours" since you did clarify in the comment that it came from a friend, although you should probably also mention that in your question. In addition, if you find that the AoPS thread I linked to fully solves the problem for you, then you may wish to delete this question. Otherwise, if there's anything unclear to you about how to solve it, then you can update your question here to specify what you're having trouble with, and asking for help with those specific issue(s). ...

Comment: (cont.) Nonetheless, keep in mind these are only my suggestions, with it being up to you whether or not to delete the question.

Comment: @JohnOmielan The SE network doesn't really mind if a problem is reproduced on another site---only if duplication occurs on this network.  Personally, I think I got nerd sniped by this problem a bit, though it is gratifying to see that the AoPS solution is similar to my own (nearly identical, modulo some notation and an initial dead end).  A "better" approach (from the perspective of the SE network) would be to reproduce the AoPS solution, with a citation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $S(n)$ denote the sum, i.e.
$$ S(n) = n + d(n) + d(d(n)) + \dotsb .$$
Note that $n$ cannot be larger than $2023$, and $d(n) \le n / 2$, as the largest divisor of $n$ is obtained by dividing $n$ by its smallest prime factor.  This implies that $1012 < n < 2024$.  This helps to reduce the search space a bit.<sup>[1]</sup>

Keeping on the theme of looking at the prime divisors of $n$, observe that if the prime factorization of $n$ is
$ n = p_1 p_2 p_3 \dotsb p_m $,
with the (possibly repeated) primes listed in decreasing order, then
\begin{align} S(n)
&= p_1 p_2 p_3 \dotsb p_m + p_1 p_2 p_3 \dotsb p_{m-1} + \dotsb + p_1 + 1 \\
&= p_1 \left( p_2 p_3 \dotsb p_m + p_2 p_3 \dotsb p_{m-1} + \dotsb + p_2 + 1\right) + 1 \\
&= p_1 S\left( \frac{n}{p_1} \right) + 1.
\end{align}
This implies that
$$ S\left( \frac{n}{p_1} \right)
= \frac{S(n)-1}{p_1}. $$
This greatly reduces the search space.  With $S(n) = 2023$, the possible choices for $p_1$ are $2$, $3$, and $337$ (the factors of $S(n)-1 = 2022$).  Then, since $p_1$ divides $S(n) - 1$, a brute force attack is possible (with a relatively small search space).

- If $p_1 = 2$ (i.e. if the largest prime factor of $n$ is $2$), then it must be the case that $n$ is a power of $2$, i.e. $n = 2^k$ for some integer $k$.  The only power of $2$ in the required range is $2^{10} = 1024$.  But
  \begin{align} S(1024) &= 1024 + 512 + 256 + 128 + 64 + 32 + 16 + 8 + 4 + 2 + 1 \\ &= 2047 \\ &\ne 2023. \end{align}
- If $p_3=3$, then
  $$ S\left( \frac{n}{3} \right) = \frac{S(n) - 1}{3} = 674. $$
  But then
  $$ S\left( \frac{n}{3p_2} \right) = \frac{673}{p_2}, $$
  where $p_2$ is the largest prime factor of $n/3$ (and thus the second largest prime factor of $n$).  But $673$ is prime, so it is its only prime factor.  Hence $S(n/2019) = 1$, which implies that $n/2019 = 1$.  Then
  $$ S(n)
  = S(2019)
  = 2019 + 673 + 1
  = 2693
  \ne 2023.$$
  Hence it is not possible that $p_1 = 3$.
- The only possibility remaining is that $p_1 = 337$.  Then
  $$ S\left( \frac{n}{337} \right) = \frac{2022}{337} = 6. $$
  Repeating the argument made above,
  $$ S\left( \frac{n}{337p_2} \right) = \frac{5}{p_2}, $$
  which implies that $p_2 = 5$, and that $S(n/1685) = 1$.  Therefore the only possibility is that $n = 1685$.  Observe that
  $$ S(n) = 1685 + 337 + 1 = 2023, $$
  as claimed.

This exhausts the three cases.  The only $n$ which gives the desired result is in the final case; this $n$ is $1685$.

---

[1] Having finished the problem now, it turns out that I didn't use any of this (well, not very much, anyway), but this search for "good" candidates by winnowing down on prime factors led me to the approach below, so I am going to leave this comment in the answer.

[*] John Omielan pointed out in the comments that a similar problem appears on [AoPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2582948p22237872).  Their solution (with $S(n) = 2021$ instead of $2023$) is remarkably similar to my own, which is both somewhat gratifying (it helps me to believe that this is correct) and incredibly annoying (as it turns out that I just did a bunch of work that someone else has already done).  But I got nerd-sniped by this problem, and put the work in, so I'll leave my answer. :/

Answer (score 1):

When we add up all the terms including $n$ & $d(n)$ , then :
(1) the last non-zero term will be $1$
(2) all other terms will have some factor common with $n$.

Here $2023-1=2022=2 \times 3 \times 337$
Thus the term before the last $1$ could be (A) $2$ (B) $3$ (C) $337$.

CASE A will not work out.
The earlier terms must be Powers of $2$
There is no way to get $2023-1-2=2020$ using Consecutive Powers of $2$.

Similarly CASE B will not work out.

### CASE C :

That will leave $2023-1-337=1685=5 \times 337$ , which could be the first term.

Hence the Solution is $n=1685$

**CHECK : $n+d(n)+d(d(n))+d(d(d(n)))=1685+337+1+0=2023$**

### ADDENDUM :

**Can there be some variation where we have 1 more term ? No**

Let it be $(XY337,Y337,337,1,0)$
We then have $(XY+Y)337=5 \times 337$
That will make $(X+1)Y=5$ which will not work out due to Prime $5$.

**In general , is the Solution Unique ? Yes**

Consider 2 Solutions
$m+d(m)+d(d(m))+\cdots+P_m+1=n+d(n)+d(d(n))+\cdots+P_n+1$

Then $m+d(m)+d(d(m))+\cdots+P_m=n+d(n)+d(d(n))+\cdots+P_n$
The largest factor on the $m$ terms & the largest factor on the $n$ terms must match to get the Equality.
When that factor is excluded , the next Equality will again force the next largest factor. Eventuality , that will make all the factors match & then terminate with $m=n$
In general , the Solution is Unique.